# When to take the math GRE, in my situation.

Tags: soft-question, gre-exam

I am a technically a freshman mathematics and computer science major at the University of Kentucky.  However, I was able to take a lot of math classes in high-school (I was home schooled) at the local university.  So at the moment I am in modern algebra 2, and topology 2.  I was wondering when I should take the math GRE, because it is going to take me at least 2 years to finish the CS program here, and I don't want to forget everything that will be on that test.  Also is there a penalty for taking the math GRE more then once?

Thank you all for the help on the weird question.

Comment: Other than the question about a penalty, this is not really something others can answer for you, it's mostly a question about your memory and how well you actually learn the subject matter of classes you take.  I don't think the exam is actually that important, but if you do, take a practice exam and figure out a plan for yourself from there.

Comment: @Callus Are you assuming the question intends to be exact? I think an approximation is fine as with blackbadger's below. OP just wants to know if there is any such pressure to take exam earlier rather than later

Comment: @BCLC Yeah, and it seems OP got something useful out of the answer as well.  I seem to have been in a less tolerant mood when I wrote my original comment, but don't totally disavow it.  All's well that ends well, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no penalty generally for taking the GRE multiple times, though *all* your scores in the last few years (2?3?5?) will be reported to the schools you apply to. My suggestion is: take it as soon as you feel ready!

Comment: 'The ScoreSelect® option lets you decide which test scores to send to the institutions you designate. As part of your four free score reports, you can send scores from your most recent test administration or from all administrations of a Subject Test taken in the last five years. After test day, you can send scores from your Most Recent, All or Any specific test administration(s) for a fee when ordering Additional Score Reports. Scores for a test administration must be reported in their entirety.'

Comment: 'The ScoreSelect option helps you approach test day with more confidence, knowing you can send the scores you feel show your personal best. It is available for both the GRE® General Test and GRE Subject Tests, and can be used by anyone with reportable scores from the last five years. For more information on your score reporting options, see Sending Your Scores.'